# R Shiny - Reactive selectInput data frame column

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, reactive-programming, shinydashboard

I have got a dashboard that pulls data from Google analytics or a CSV upload and then calculate conversion rate and average order value(for AB testing purpose).
I have been trying to implement filters that allow selecting device category e.g (mobile, tablet or desktop) and product category e.g(card, gift or flowers). The filters should pulled from from the data frame dynamically and then be available for selection in the drop downs.
I have seen a lot of similar example of this forum but for the life of me I haven't been able to make it work. The cases I have seen seem to be using observe ({}) but my issue seem to be coming from the fact that I need to pass the choices out of the reactive function first.

Below is a reproducible, simplified example, with data frame generated as they would appear.
I have commented out #choices= Results()$Devices in the UI so to show you how it looks like before it breaks.

Many thanks in advance
G

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(googleVis)
require(dplyr)


ui <- dashboardPage(  
  skin="blue",

  dashboardHeader(
    title="Dashboard",
    titleWidth = 250

  ),

  dashboardSidebar(


    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Calculator ", tabName = "calculator", icon = icon("calculator"))

    )
  ),
  #
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "calculator",
              h1("Calculator"),


              fluidRow(
                column(width = 1,
                       selectInput("device","Device:",
                                   #choices= Results()$Devices,
                                   multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)
                ),
                column(width = 1,
                       selectInput("product","Product:",
                                   #"choices= Results()$Products",
                                   multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)
                )
              ),

              fluidRow(

                column(width = 6,
                       box(title="Overall Conversion rate %",status="primary",solidHeader = TRUE,
                           htmlOutput("CRABCalcl"),width = "100%",height=275)
                ),

                column(width = 6,
                       box(title="Overall AOV £",status="primary",solidHeader = TRUE,
                           htmlOutput("AOVABCalcl"),width = "100%",height=275)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(

                column(width = 6,
                       box(title="Ecommerce Conversion rate %",status="primary",solidHeader = TRUE,
                           htmlOutput("CRABCalclEHC"),width = "100%",height=275)
                ),

                column(width = 6,
                       box(title="Ecoomerce AOV £",status="primary",solidHeader = TRUE,
                           htmlOutput("AOVABCalclEHC"),width = "100%",height=275)
                )
              )

          )

      )#End of tab Item
    ) #end of tabItems

  )#End of Dashboard body
)#End of dashboardPage


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  Results <- reactive({

    myDataRAW<-data.frame(
      c("mobile","mobile","desktop","desktop","tablet","tablet"),
      c("Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger"),
      c(34355,34917,28577,29534,15337,13854),
      c(15011,15427,32190,32548,40299,40858),
      c(14636,14990,19609,19702,7214,7785),
      c(123273.70,20936.92,45179.05,46359.91,65765.27,92771.36),
      c(10370,13403,19241,26965,4468,8796)
    )

    myDataRAWEHC<-data.frame(
      c("desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","tablet","tablet","desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","tablet","tablet","tablet","tablet","desktop","desktop"),
      c("Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Gift","Gift","Gift","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Flower","Flower"),
      c("Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Large","Large","Large","Large","Square","Square","Square","Square","Large","Large","Square","Square","Flowers","Flowers"),
      c("Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger"),
      c(8767,18072,5729,13017,2908,7086,1655,2971,1008,2177,984,2369,599,1422,449,1052,402,1001,233,355),
      c(9055,18624,5908,13302,3015,7288,1691,3000,1013,2192,1009,2455,623,1450,455,1068,413,1017,233,356),
      c(21699.60,44480.95,14464.85,32590.30,7232.47,17483.35,8309.85,14684.68,5024.92,10844.67,2405.07,5826.83,1529.16,3556.38,2220.21,5192.92,992.14,2447.78,5196.08,8021.95)
    )

    names(myDataRAW)<-c("Device.Category","Segment","Users","Sessions","Transactions","Revenue","Quantity")
    names(myDataRAWEHC)<-c("Device.Category","Product.Category..Enhanced.Ecommerce.","Product.Variant","Segment","Unique.Purchases","Quantity","Product.Revenue")

    Devices<-myDataRAW$Device.Category
    Products<-unique(myDataRAWEHC$Product.Category..Enhanced.Ecommerce.)
#     DeviceFilter<-input$device
#     ProductFilter<-input$product
    #the below is replacing the above input to act as filters
    DeviceFilter<-c("desktop","mobile")
    ProductFilter<-c("Flower","Gift")
    myData<-myDataRAW %>% filter(Device.Category %in% DeviceFilter)
    myDataEHC<-myDataRAWEHC %>% filter(Device.Category %in% DeviceFilter) %>% filter(`Product.Category..Enhanced.Ecommerce.` %in% ProductFilter)

    myData<-bind_rows(myData,myData %>% group_by(Device.Category="All",Segment) %>% summarise(Users=sum(Users),Sessions=sum(Sessions),Transactions=sum(Transactions),Revenue=sum(Revenue),Quantity=sum(Quantity)))
    myDataEHC<-rbind(myDataEHC %>% group_by(Device.Category,Segment) %>% summarise(Transactions=sum(Unique.Purchases),Quantity=sum(Quantity),Revenue=sum(Product.Revenue)), 
                     myDataEHC %>% group_by(Device.Category="All",Segment) %>% summarise(Transactions=sum(Unique.Purchases),Quantity=sum(Quantity),Revenue=sum(Product.Revenue)) )
    myDataEHC<-left_join(myDataEHC,myData %>% select(Segment,Device.Category,Users,Sessions))
    myData$Analysis<-"Overall"
    myDataEHC$Analysis<-"Ecommerce"
    myDataForAnalysis<-rbind(as.data.frame(myData),as.data.frame(myDataEHC))


    myDataForAnalysis$CVR<-myDataForAnalysis$Transactions/myDataForAnalysis$Sessions
    myDataForAnalysis$AOV<-myDataForAnalysis$Revenue/myDataForAnalysis$Transactions

    DisplayResultsEHC<-myDataForAnalysis %>% filter(Analysis %in% "Ecommerce")
    DisplayResults<-myDataForAnalysis %>% filter(Analysis %in% "Overall")



    list(DisplayResultsEHC=DisplayResultsEHC,DisplayResults=DisplayResults,Devices=Devices,Products=Products)
  })



  output$CRABCalcl <- renderGvis({
    DataABCalcl<-Results()$DisplayResults
    F<-cast(DataABCalcl, Device.Category~Segment, value = 'CVR')
    X<-gvisColumnChart(F,options=list(legend="{position:'top'}",width="100%"))

  })

  output$AOVABCalcl <- renderGvis({
    DataABCalcl<-Results()$DisplayResults
    F<-cast(DataABCalcl, Device.Category~Segment, value = 'AOV')
    X<-gvisColumnChart(F,options=list(legend="{position:'top'}",width="100%"))
  })

  output$CRABCalclEHC <- renderGvis({
    DataABCalcl<-Results()$DisplayResultsEHC
    F<-cast(DataABCalcl, Device.Category~Segment, value = 'CVR')
    X<-gvisColumnChart(F,options=list(legend="{position:'top'}",width="100%"))

  })

  output$AOVABCalclEHC <- renderGvis({
    DataABCalcl<-Results()$DisplayResultsEHC
    F<-cast(DataABCalcl, Device.Category~Segment, value = 'AOV')
    X<-gvisColumnChart(F,options=list(legend="{position:'top'}",width="100%"))
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see a good start would be to create a global.R file containing (and remove from server.R):

global.R

```
myDataRAW<-data.frame(
            c("mobile","mobile","desktop","desktop","tablet","tablet"),
            c("Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger"),
            c(34355,34917,28577,29534,15337,13854),
            c(15011,15427,32190,32548,40299,40858),
            c(14636,14990,19609,19702,7214,7785),
            c(123273.70,20936.92,45179.05,46359.91,65765.27,92771.36),
            c(10370,13403,19241,26965,4468,8796)
    )

    myDataRAWEHC<-data.frame(
            c("desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","tablet","tablet","desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","desktop","desktop","mobile","mobile","tablet","tablet","tablet","tablet","desktop","desktop"),
            c("Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Gift","Gift","Gift","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Card","Flower","Flower"),
            c("Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Standard","Large","Large","Large","Large","Square","Square","Square","Square","Large","Large","Square","Square","Flowers","Flowers"),
            c("Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger","Control","Challenger"),
            c(8767,18072,5729,13017,2908,7086,1655,2971,1008,2177,984,2369,599,1422,449,1052,402,1001,233,355),
            c(9055,18624,5908,13302,3015,7288,1691,3000,1013,2192,1009,2455,623,1450,455,1068,413,1017,233,356),
            c(21699.60,44480.95,14464.85,32590.30,7232.47,17483.35,8309.85,14684.68,5024.92,10844.67,2405.07,5826.83,1529.16,3556.38,2220.21,5192.92,992.14,2447.78,5196.08,8021.95)
    )

    names(myDataRAW)<-c("Device.Category","Segment","Users","Sessions","Transactions","Revenue","Quantity")
    names(myDataRAWEHC)<-c("Device.Category","Product.Category..Enhanced.Ecommerce.","Product.Variant","Segment","Unique.Purchases","Quantity","Product.Revenue")
```

This allows you to access myDataRAW and myDataRAWEHC from ui.R. Modify the ui.R accordingly:

```
fluidRow(
                                    column(width = 3,
                                           selectInput("device","Device:",
                                                       choices= levels(myDataRAW$Device.Category),
                                                       multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)
                                    ),
                                    column(width = 3,
                                           selectInput("product","Product:",
                                                       choices= unique(levels(myDataRAWEHC$Product.Category..Enhanced.Ecommerce.)),
                                                       multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE)
                                    )
                            ),
```

after that you still have some work left to rearrange the server.R part.