# How to call a column from a data frame generated by reactive() in R shiny?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a text file such like:

```
    df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(9), 
               y=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3), 
               z=rep(LETTERS[4:6], each=3))
    write.table(df, "test.txt")
```

What I wanted is to let user to type in a selected column such as `y` and then select two levels, `level0`, `level1` from the dropdown options of the column (e.g. `A`, `B`, `C` in column `y`). I tried the below script:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( textInput("design", "Column to pick", " "),
                 uiOutput("level0"),
                 uiOutput("level1")
             )

server <- function(input, output) {
  ##main results output
  datobj <- reactive({
    dat <- read.table(input$file)
    return(list(x=dat$x, 
                y=dat$y))
  })

  output$level0 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ref0", "Reference group", datobj()[["y"]])
  })

    output$level1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ref1", "Study group", datobj()[["y"]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have been stuck whole morning for this as well as some online posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415021/r-shiny-reactive-selectinput-data-frame-column), but still can't make it work. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for.

I added a `fileInput` for choosing file to upload. In addition, I changed the `textInput` to a `selectInput` so you could select the column instead of typing it in.

An `observe` will update your `selectInput` once file uploaded, and column names will be used as choices for `design`.

The `output` will subset the data based on `input$design` selection. I'm not sure that was what you wanted.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( fileInput('file1', 'Choose File'),
                 selectInput("design", "Column to pick", " "),
                 uiOutput("level0"),
                 uiOutput("level1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataobj <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    tbl <- read.table(input$file1$datapath)
    return(tbl)
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "design", choices = names(dataobj()))
  })

  output$level0 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ref0", "Reference group", dataobj()[[input$design]])
  })

  output$level1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("ref1", "Study group", dataobj()[[input$design]])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```